# Missing Pin Codes in Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding

I have an android app that handles logistics for me in my city (Mumbai, India). The user types in his address followed by his pin code. I use google maps API to find the (lat, long) of the area marked by the pin code and calculate which one of my stores is closest to it. That store fulfills the customer's order. So far it has been fairly successful but recently I discovered some users orders were not tended to because an error was returned on querying the pin code's location.

This is the url i send an HttpRequest to

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:"+uri[0]+"|country:india"
```

So for example if I type the link below. I get the approximate location of the vicinity marked as 400006

"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:400006|country:india"

But If i input some pin codes such 400036, where I have been getting orders from the JSON I get returned is this

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Could someone please help me out/ explain what exactly is happening. There are a few other pin codes where I am not getting a result.